# PIG convert text lines to sparse vector

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have to files that I need to combine together using Apache PIG.  First file contains list of book titles, like this with each title being on the line by itself.

```
Ted Dunning,  Mahout in Action
Leo Tolstoy,  War and Peace
Douglas Adams, The hitchhiker guide to the galaxy.
James Sununu,  galaxy III for Dummies
Tom McArthur,  The War we went to
```

the second file is the list of words and their IDs.  Like this

```
ted, 12
tom, 13
douglas, 14
galaxy, 15
war, 16
leo, 17
peace, 18
```

I need to join these two files to produce the output like this:

for the line 'Leo Tolstoy, War and piece' it should produce

```
17:1,16:1,18:1
```

for the line 'Tom McArthur,  The War we went to'  it should produce

```
13:1,16:1
```

In other words, I need to perform the join using the word as a key.  So far I've written the following code in pig

```
titles = LOAD 'Titles' AS ( title : chararray );  
termIDs = LOAD  'TermIDs' AS (  term:chararray,id:int);

A = SAMPLE titles 0.01;
X = FOREACH A GENERATE STRSPLIT(title,'[ _\\[\\]\\/,\\.\\(\\)]+');
```

This gives gets both files loaded  and X contains the list of BAGS each bag containing the terms that occur on the corresponding line.  Like this:

```
((ted,dunning,mahout,in,action))
((leo,tolstoy,war,and,peace))
```

For the reason of being late on Saturday night,  I can't figure out the way to JOIN step without writing a UDF or using streaming.  Is it even possible to do using only PIG primitives.

Comment: Is the order of the ids for each title important?

Comment: No,  I don't care about the order.  This output is going to clustering / classification algorithms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can FLATTEN the results of the TOKENIZE, thus all of the bag become rows and now you can join the X relation with termsID.

```
X = foreach A generate title, flatten(TOKENIZE(title)) as term;
J = join X by (term),  termIDs by (term);
G = group J by title;
Result = foreach G generate group as title, termIDs.id;
```

The above code was typed on my mobile phone, so it was not debugged.

**UPDATE 1:**

For cases when it is preferable to use STRSPLIT instead of TOKENIZE you could do a combination of FLATTEN and TOBAG to achieve the same effect as TOKENIZE, which is getting a bag of words from a tuple returned by STRSPLIT.

```
SPLT = foreach A generate title, FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(title,'[ _\\[\\]\\/,\\.\\(\\)]+'));
X_tmp = foreach SPLT generate $0 as title, FLATTEN(TOBAG($1..$20)) as term; -- pivots the row
X = filter X_tmp by term is not null; -- this removes the extra bag rows when title was split in less than 20 terms
J = join X by (term),  termIDs by (term) using 'replicated';
G = group J by title;
Result = foreach G generate group as title, termIDs.id;
```

If any of the title exceeds 20 terms than increase the number in the TOBAG.

Comment: Thanks. It is a step in right direction.  There are only two things I am concerned with.  The 'title' is actually pretty long so doing this would double the storage requirements, but hey it least it will get the job done.  The second is more serious.  I can't use TOKENIZE because the terms are not nicely separated by spaces. I actually have to use the regular expression above.  Guess I can write a UDF that will handle this. Thanks anyway

Comment: To address the biggest issue of not using TOKENIZE see the UPDATE 1.