# UnGroup in Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

Does Apache Pig support an UNGROUP operation ? I guess No. So could any one help me out with this probblem? 
I have a rows of the form

```
1,a-b-c
2,d-e-f
3,g-h
```

I would like to expand it to the form

```
1,a
1,b
1,c
2,d
2,e
2,f
3,g
3,h
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably use the builtin `STRSPLIT` to split your second field into several tokens, and then apply `FLATTEN` to create 1 row per element. Something like this:

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' as (id, data);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE id, FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(data,'-'));
```

Comment: STRSPLIT returns a tuple and not a bag, it will not pivot the data values into the rows, you will end up with the same number of tuples as your input data. To get the result you want take a look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549842/pig-convert-text-lines-to-sparse-vector/12568662#12568662

Comment: Just tried it and it worked. Replace '-' with spaces and than TOKENIZE, as it returns a BAG and after FLATTEN it creates the pivoted rows. B = FOREACH A GENERATE id, FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(REPLACE(data, '-', ' ')));